# CodeIgniter 3 HMVC - Unable to locate the model you have specified

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3, hmvc

**current structure**

```
application
-modules
--Users
---controllers
----Users.php --- class Users
--Wide
---models
----Wide_model.php --- class Wide_model
```

**autoload.php**

```
$autoload['model'] = array('Wide/Wide_model');
```

---

things that I have already tried

1. Changing file name to lowercase i.e `wide_model.php`, replacing autoload with `Wide/wide_model`
2. Changing module name to lowercase i.e wide, replacing autoload with wide/wide_model
3. Changing file name to uppercase i.e `Wide_model.php` but keeping module name to lower case, autoload to `wide/Wide_model`

---

**Wide_model.php**

```
class Wide_model extends CI_Model {

    public function insert($table, $data) {
        $data['modify'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        if ($this->db->insert($table, $data)) {
            return "true";
        } else {
            return "false";
        }
    }
```

---

```
$autoload['model'] = array('Wide/Wide_model');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. (Tested)

---

Go to your model file and **rename it** to

```
Wide_model.php --> wide_model.php
```

---

and go to `autoload.php` & **change this**

```
$autoload['model'] = array('Wide/wide_model');
```

---

To access model functions **use this**

```
$this->wide_model->FunctionName();
```

Comment: same error didn't work, model is not getting auto load
if I remove autoload then default controller will be loaded, not only that, all controller and views is working fine, except db work - insert, update and delete;  as wide_model is common for all controller

Comment: if wide model is commn thennplace it in model file in application root

Comment: still same error - can you check it, if share code - 70% project is done; working fine in windows, now have to upload , now working in Linux

Comment: Share on what ?? nothing added in question

Comment: can give online ftp credential or share with email

Comment: email sent, please check it